I'm displaying my jaspersoft report details vertically.. how can I display the totals of these details as the right most column?
I updated my report to display vertically so my Fiscal years appear as columns instead of rows.  I also created variables to aggregate all these fiscal years values.  How can I display these totals as the last column of my table (like in the image)


I read that I could add them to the footer setting it to "floating column footer" so they would print right after the last "column" but I'm either doing it wrong or it doesn't work that way.
